# How to Align bottom footer element after my text ends

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, footer

This could be very easy solution but i cant seem to fix or find it for hours now. How can i have my transparent footer block stick to bottom of page after the text. I know sounds easy but cant see to make it work?

Any suggestions would be grateful, thanks again Stewart

```css
    body {
    background-color: #828282;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}
    .footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
    .text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%); /* center */
}
```

```html
<div class="text" style="min-width:400px;max-width:700px;">
<h1>TERMS OF USE FOR ALL USERS</h1>

<br><br>

<b>BY USING OUR WEBSITE YOU AGREE TO THESE TERMS – PLEASE READ THEM CAREFULLY. Introduction: These Terms of Use for all Users govern your use of Venus and your agreement with us. Interpretation: In the Terms of Service:</b>

<br><br>

To reflect changes in laws and regulatory requirements which apply to Venus and the services, features and programs of Venus where such changes require Venus to change its terms and conditions in a manner which does not allow us to give reasonable notice to you; and to address an unforeseen and imminent danger related to defending Venus, Fans or Creators from fraud, malware, spam, data breaches or other cybersecurity risks. We may also make other changes to any part of the Terms of Service, and we will give you reasonable notice of such changes by email or through Venus, and you may contact us to end your agreement with us before the changes take effect. Once any updated Terms of Service are in effect, you will be bound by them if you continue to use Venus.

<br><br>

To reflect changes in laws and regulatory requirements which apply to Venus and the services, features and programs of Venus where such changes require Venus to change its terms and conditions in a manner which does not allow us to give reasonable notice to you; and to address an unforeseen and imminent danger related to defending Venus, Fans or Creators from fraud, malware, spam, data breaches or other cybersecurity risks. We may also make other changes to any part of the Terms of Service, and we will give you reasonable notice of such changes by email or through Venus, and you may contact us to end your agreement with us before the changes take effect. Once any updated Terms of Service are in effect, you will be bound by them if you continue to use Venus.

<br><br>

To reflect changes in laws and regulatory requirements which apply to Venus and the services, features and programs of Venus where such changes require Venus to change its terms and conditions in a manner which does not allow us to give reasonable notice to you; and to address an unforeseen and imminent danger related to defending Venus, Fans or Creators from fraud, malware, spam, data breaches or other cybersecurity risks. We may also make other changes to any part of the Terms of Service, and we will give you reasonable notice of such changes by email or through Venus, and you may contact us to end your agreement with us before the changes take effect. Once any updated Terms of Service are in effect, you will be bound by them if you continue to use Venus.

</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: what do you exactly mean, be always at the bottom of the screen or just be at the bottom of the text (while scrolling in or out of the screen)? Also as a site not you should work on your techniques. TranslateX  is a terrible way to center elements in such easy task where you simply could use `flexbox` or `marign: o auto;`. Also if you use `<br><br>` you do something wrong. Use `margin-bottom`  instead. Then use `<p>` paragraphs insetad of `<b>` bold if you want to to have paragraphs.

Comment: thx tacoshy. here is a image to explain it better. https://ibb.co/smrK2f7

Comment: I tried all the css position functions (absolute, relative etc), but none of them works!

Comment: why are you using absolute positioning for content and footer? I would not recommend